# Select android os name based on version number

Tags: android, python, version

First of all, nice day to everyone!

My code needs to detect which android version is being used on by means of `getprop ro.build.version.release`. I do so using systems with root and python for android.

For the time being the devices I tested the code things were working nice but partially of course because I haven't taking into consideration the updates in between new os versions. I just added the new version I was testing on to a dictionary.

So let's say I have this dictionary:

`VersionName = {'4.0':"Ice Cream Sandwich", '4.0.4':"Ice Cream Sandwich", '4.1':"Jelly Bean", '4.2':"Jelly Bean", '4.3':"Jelly Bean", '4.4':"KitKat", '5.0':"Lollipop", '5.1':'Lollipop', '6.0':"Marshmallow", '7.1.1':"Nougat"}`

I would add:

`'4.4.2':'KitKat'`

To save and detect the new version I was working on but that's not going to work. To overcome this I just simply made a search to select the first and the last release of an android version.

`VersionName = {'Ice Cream Sandwich':['4.0', '4.0.4'], 'Jelly Bean':['4.1', '4.3.1'], 'KitKat':['4.4', '4.4.4'], 'Lollipop':['5.0', '5.1.1'], 'Marshmallow':['6.0', '6.0.1'], 'Nougat':['7.0', '7.1.1']}`

The problems comes if the update version is in between the two values.

Given `{'KitKat':['4.4', '4.4.4']}` and device version `4.4.2` how can I detect if it's part of **KitKat**

Comment: Is it now possible to do android using python? Is this an official  thing.

Comment: Sure it is @ChrisHarris! In fact it's been around for awhile. A project started on googlecode and that now is being maintained on github. You get an RPC server that translate python calls to android native java instructions if I'm not wrong in the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe store the min and max as two variables, then do if os(version)> (min value):
then check if os(version) < (max value)

Comment: I'll give it a try then. I tried something similar but I there was a bad evaluation of values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach the problem with the help provided! There are better ways I know that much so if anyone has another method please share.

```
def DroidName(ReleaseVersion):

   # ReleaseVersion = '4.4.2'
   VersionValue = {'Ice Cream Sandwich':['4.0', '4.0.4'], 'Jelly Bean':['4.1', '4.3.1'], 'KitKat':['4.4', '4.4.4'], 'Lollipop':['5.0', '5.1.1'], 'Marshmallow':['6.0', '6.0.1'], 'Nougat':['7.0', '7.1.1']}

   for i in VersionValue.items():
      AndroidName = i[0]
      MinimalValue = i[1][0]
      MaximunValue = i[1][1]
      if ReleaseVersion >= MinimalValue and ReleaseVersion <= MaximunValue:
         print AndroidName, ReleaseVersion
         break
```